# Setting the body of a http-proxy-middleware Proxied Request

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

I'm still new still newish to node, and having some troubling figuring out how to set a new response body with the `http-proxy-middleware` package.

That is, I have the following small program that proxies requests

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var app = express();

app.use('**', proxy({
    target: 'http://alanstorm.com', 
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyRes:function (proxyRes, req, res) {

        //I want to do something here to change the response
        console.log("Called");
        console.log(proxyRes);
        console.log(res);
    }
}));
app.listen(3000);
```

i.e. -- I can make a request to `http://localhost:3000`, and it will proxy the request to my personal website.

I've also successfully setup a response listener (`onProxyRes`) above.  I seem to have access to a proxy response object, a request object, and a response object.  What I'd like to do is, in the `onProxyRes` method, is **change** the response if certain things are true or not.

However, it's not clear how to do this with the `proxyRes` or `res` objects, and I'm not sure how to look up the available methods on these objects.  I tried `console.log`ing them for useful properties, and found nothing useful.

If someone know how i can modify the bodies of the response objects, that would be great.  If someone can tell me how I can figure out what methods exist on those objects, that would be extra great.

Comment: Using a debugger would allow you to explore the objects, see https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: @skirtle woah, neat!  Thanks for the tip.  What moden times we live in.